# Specific order of two elements inside xsd:choice

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="CodeTags">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="text" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            ...
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="reference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            ...
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="switch" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            ...
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="if" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            ...
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="else" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            ...
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="param" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            ...
        </xs:element>       
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want that the `else` tag just appears after the `if` tag.  How can I achieve this? I already put them into a `<xs:sequence>` order but I was still able to enter an `else` tag anywhere with other tags between it and the `if` tag.

EDIT: Code snippet was posted as a picture, now changed to a code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `if` and `else` together in an `xs:sequence` as one of the choices:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <!-- ... -->
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="if"/>
    <xs:element ref="else"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <!-- ... -->
<xs:choice>
```

You can also remove the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` from each of the choices; placing them on the `xs:choice` itself will suffice for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I also could manage, that the if-tag can be alone but if you use else, an if-tag must be before. To achieve this, I added a minOccurs="0" to the else declaration.

Answer (score 1):

To learn how to handle this situation better, I suggest you start by understanding the meaning of the CodeTags element you have written, and why it allows sequences of elements you would rather not allow.  Then continue by understanding why the solution offered by kjhughes works.